# Download Files from URL using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have few urls which are linked to a pdf example

abc.com/1.pdf
abc.com/2g.pdf
abc.com/i8.pdf

What i wanted to do is Download the PDFs automatically in a Folder using Classic ASP

I tried to use this code http://blog.netnerds.net/2007/01/classic-asp-push-file-downloads-from-directory-outside-of-the-web-root/ 
but this doesnt work for Http it works good if the files are local.

I want to do it automatically.

Answer (score 13):

I used the code posted by user580950 and the comment by AnthonyWJones and created a function version of the code.  Call the function and it returns the content type of the file downloaded or an empty string if the file wasn't found.

```
public function SaveFileFromUrl(Url, FileName)
    dim objXMLHTTP, objADOStream, objFSO

    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", Url, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then 
        Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objADOStream.Open
        objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
        objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

        Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(FileName) Then objFSO.DeleteFile FileName
        Set objFSO = Nothing

        objADOStream.SaveToFile FileName
        objADOStream.Close
        Set objADOStream = Nothing

        SaveFileFromUrl = objXMLHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
    else
        SaveFileFromUrl = ""
    End if

    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
end function
```

Comment: I get "write to file failed". This function is missing an option for a location to save to. Nor do I get a prompt to select a location to save to.

Comment: how do you call this function on the <a href ?

Answer (score 9):

I got this code somewhere on the internet if anyone wants to use it.

```
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout = 60 * 20
' Set your settings
strFileURL = "http://pathtofile.zip"
strHDLocation = "c:\filename.zip"

' Fetch the file
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
objXMLHTTP.Send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
    objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Change "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" to "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0" (xmlhttp is not safe for use in ASP server code).

Comment: This does work while the function shown above gives an error. However it is missing the option of where to save to. Consequently the user has no idea that the file was downloaded or where to find it.