# CDONTS sending an email with attachments - Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, cdonts

I want to send an email with attachments using CDONTS. But, here is what i am using:

CDO_MAIL.AttachFile "http://SampleWebSite.com/Sample.asp?COMMAND=6"

In JavaScript we are doing:

image1.src = "http://SampleWebSite.com/Sample.asp?COMMAND=6"

The problem is - I do not have the exact image name. The above URL returns me an image. Can you please let me know how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diodeus is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466860/215042). However, another way to "solve" this is to [download the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496675/download-files-from-url-using-classic-asp) so you have it locally and *then* attach it. Embedding in the HTML, as suggested by Diodeus, will cause most mail clients to block the image and require user interaction to download the image. It's better to do it [attach it and reference it by CID](http://support.jodohost.com/threads/tut-how-to-add-embedded-images-in-cdo-mail.7692/).

Comment: I want to save this on disk and then attach it to my email - "http://SampleWebSite.com/Sample.asp?COMMAND=6". Can you provide me sample code for that ?

Comment: There are, besides the link to Diodeus' post, two links in my answer that should provide you all the code you need to a) download a file and b) attach it and reference it by CID. If you want me to write your code then you can pay as my other customers have to too ;-)

Answer (score -1):

CDO does not support HTTP. It's expecting a **local** file reference (C:....).

You can embed the image in the message body though, using simple HTML:

```
<img src="http://SampleWebSite.com/Sample.asp?COMMAND=6" />
```