# VBS/Batch Check if Download Complete

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, download, wget

Is there any way using VBS with its default options (without [WGet](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/506439/Downloading-files-with-VBScript), PowerShell, etc.) to check if a downloaded file is completely 100% downloaded?

The [script I'm using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496675/download-files-from-url-using-classic-asp) successfully downloads files, but I don't know how to check if the file is 100% downloaded and haven't been able to find a way to do this with default Windows (7/8) features (without having to enable custom features).

Alternately, if this is possible with Batch (or any other default Windows features for that matter) from within the VBS script, this would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a mixed script [Batch/Vbscript] to download a file from a URL typed by the user from inputBox.

```
@echo off
mode con:cols=70 lines=8 & Color 9B
Title -==*==- Batch Downloader file by Hackoo -==*==-
(
echo Option Explicit
echo.
echo Dim Message, result
echo Dim Title, Text1, Text2
echo.
echo Message = "Type the URL of the file to download."        
echo Title = "Download a file from URL by Hackoo"
echo Text1 = "You canceled"
echo.
echo result = InputBox^(Message, Title, "http://www.gametop.com/online-free-games/anti-terror-force-online/game.swf", 900, 900^)
echo.
echo.
echo If result = "" Then
echo    WScript.Echo Text1
echo Else
echo    WScript.Echo result
echo End If
)>"%tmp%\inputbox.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %%a in ('Cscript "%tmp%\inputbox.vbs" //nologo') do (set "a=%%a")
(
echo path = "%A%"
echo pos = InStrRev(path, "/"^) +1
echo Const DownloadDest = "%A%"
echo LocalFile = Mid(path, pos^)
echo Const webUser = "admin"
echo Const webPass = "admin"
echo Const DownloadType = "binary"
echo dim strURL
echo.
echo function getit(^)
echo  dim xmlhttp
echo.
echo  set xmlhttp=createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"^)
echo  'xmlhttp.SetOption 2, 13056 'If https -^) Ignorer toutes les erreurs SSL
echo  strURL = DownloadDest
echo  Wscript.Echo "Download-URL: " ^& strURL
echo.
echo  'Pour l'authentification de base, utilisez la liste ci-dessous, ainsi que les variables + d'utilisateurs? laisser passer
echo  'xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false, WebUser, WebPass
echo  xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false
echo.
echo  xmlhttp.Send
echo  Wscript.Echo "Download-Status: " ^& xmlhttp.Status ^& " " ^& xmlhttp.statusText
echo.
echo  If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
echo    Dim objStream
echo    set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"^)
echo    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
echo    objStream.Open
echo    objStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
echo    objStream.SaveToFile LocalFile,2
echo    objStream.Close
echo    set objStream = Nothing
echo  End If
echo.
echo.
echo  set xmlhttp=Nothing
echo End function
echo.
echo '=======================================================================
echo ' Fin Defs de fonction, Start Page
echo '=======================================================================
echo getit(^)
echo Wscript.Echo "Download Completed. Check " ^& LocalFile ^& " for success."
echo Wscript.Quit(intOK^)
)>"%tmp%\httpdownload.vbs"
::Debut
echo Please wait ... The downloading file is in progress ...
echo.
for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %%a in ('Cscript "%tmp%\httpdownload.vbs" //nologo') do (echo "%%a")
Del %tmp%\httpdownload.vbs
::fin
pause>nul
```

Comment: Very nice. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I made another Vbscript with a Waiting Bar in HTA for a large file to download,so you can give a try and i hope that it will work on Windows 8 because i don't test it yet on this environment.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,WaitingMsg,oExec,fso,ws,Temp,ExampleURL,URL,PathScript,Question,MaCmd
Title = "Downloading File by © Hackoo 2014"
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
ExampleURL = "http://promodj.com/download/4126268/Chris%20Parker%20-%20Life%20MIX%20%282011%20-%202013%29%20%28promodj.com%29.mp3"
URL = InputBox("Type or paste the URL in the inputbox Example : " & Dblquote(ExampleURL) & "",Title,ExampleURL)
If URL = "" Then Wscript.Quit()
Call DownloadingFile(URL) 'Downloading the file
'********************************************************************************************************************
Sub DownloadingFile(URL)
    Dim Title,objFSO,Ws,objXMLHTTP,PathScript,Tab,strHDLocation,objADOStream,Command,Start,File
    Dim MsgTitle,WaitingMsg,StartTime,DurationTime,ProtocoleHTTP
    Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    PathScript = fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) 'Path of this Vbscript
    ProtocoleHTTP = "http://"
    If URL = "" Then WScript.Quit
    If Left(URL,7) <> ProtocoleHTTP Then
        URL = ProtocoleHTTP & URL
    End if
    Tab = split(url,"/")
    File =  Tab(UBound(Tab))
    File = Replace(File,"%20"," ")
    File = Replace(File,"%28","(")
    File = Replace(File,"%29",")")
    WaitingMsg = "Please wait ... "& DblQuote(File) &" is in progress..."
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    strHDLocation = PathScript & "\" & File
    Title = "Downloading "& DblQuote(File) &" by © Hackoo 2014"
    Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
    Call LancerProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
    StartTime = Timer 'Start the Timer Counter
    On Error Resume Next
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET",URL,false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        Call FermerProgressBar()'Closing Waiting Bar
        MsgBox err.description,16,err.description
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
            strHDLocation = PathScript & "\" & File
            Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            objADOStream.Open
            objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
            objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
            objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
            objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation,2
            objADOStream.Close
            Set objADOStream = Nothing
        End If
    End if
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
    DurationTime = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0) & " seconds." 'The duration of the script
    Call FermerProgressBar() 'Closing Waiting Bar
    ws.Popup "The Download of " & Dblquote(File) & " is finished in " & DurationTime &" !","5","The Download of " & Dblquote(File) & " is finished in " & DurationTime &" !",64
End Sub
'***********************************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 490,110"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```