# Loading dialog while opening Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to bring up a dialog which tells the user to wait until the Excel file and program is loaded.

How can I bring up a dialog in my VBS?

My used VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel, objWorkBook

//start dialog here?

Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
objExcel.Visible = false
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Tester.xlsm")
objExcel.Run "Tester.xlsm!modul1.subTest"
objWorkBook.Close True
objExcel.Quit
Set objWorkBook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: What did you mean about dialog ?
Did you mean like a MsgBox or a Popup Message ? or a Waiting Bar like in this example ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734096/vbs-batch-check-if-download-complete/25735194#25735194

Comment: Thx. sth like that but not that complex^^

Comment: I thought sth like open a window and wait until the xlsm is opend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing some code from the [Scripting Guy Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/08/18/how-can-i-minimize-or-hide-an-html-application-for-30-seconds.aspx) you could use an HTA as your splash/loading screen, and move it off-screen once the workbook is opened:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Splash Screen</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
     APPLICATIONNAME="Splash Screen"
     SCROLL="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="normal"
     BORDER="none"
     INNERBORDER="no"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
  Dim xl, wb

  Sub Window_OnLoad
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Tester.xlsm")

    screenWidth  = document.parentWindow.screen.availWidth
    screenHeight = document.parentWindow.screen.availHeight
    window.moveTo -(screenWidth + 50), -(screenHeight + 50)

    xl.Run "Tester.xlsm!modul1.subTest"

    wb.Close True
    xl.Quit

    self.close
  End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p>Loading Excel. Please wait.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: txt i will try this :D