# How to know whether the download is complete

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to download a software from ftp location. When the download is completed, installation should start. May i know how to check whether the Download is completed or not using VBscript.

This is the current logic I am using But i get **Object Required:"** error

I am instantiating the vbscript from jar file

```
set shell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate ("Internet Explorer")


Dim objHTTP

Do
wscript.sleep 100
Loop While( objHTTP.readyState <> 4 ) And ( objHTTP.readyState <> "complete" ) 

msgbox ("download completed")
```

Comment: You code seems incomplete. If you want to check your download status, it has to be started with your "objHTTP" object. It can't check download started by another object.

Comment: Actually I am instantiating my vbscript from a jar file:                            set shell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate ("Internet Explorer")
wscript.sleep 10000

Dim objHTTP

Do
wscript.sleep 100
Loop While( objHTTP.readyState <> 4 ) And ( objHTTP.readyState <> "complete" ) 

msgbox ("download completed")

Comment: Take a look at this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734096/vbs-batch-check-if-download-complete/25735194#25735194

Answer (score 1):

**shell** and **objHTTP** objects are not linked together and they can't be.
You can't check download started from **shell** with **objHTTP**, you need to manage the entire download with **objHTTP** object.

Here's what you can do to manage your download :

```
Const BINARY = 1
Const CREATE = 2

' Download 7-ZIP 64bits.
myUrl = "http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z938-x64.msi"
' Save to disk in that file.
myFile = "c:\temp\7z938-x64.msi"

Set oHttp = WScript.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oHttp.open "Get", myURL, False
oHttp.send

Set oStream = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.type = BINARY
oStream.open
oStream.write oHTTP.ResponseBody
oStream.SaveToFile myFile, CREATE
ostream.Close
```

*Also, not the most clean answer, but if you know it, you can check when the downloaded file reaches its size in your loop.*