# How to download a file without browser and open/save dialog batch maybe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, vbscript, network-programming

I'm asking that what other method to download a file from internet other than browsers and other softwares, i think is possible with CMD(command line), batch script ?
To be more exactly to use a windows (let say 7) component to download a file without a dialog like vbs, hta, ..etc, is possible? I dont want to download wget, curl, telnet or other component
This will work on windows 7?
http://semitwist.com/articles/article/view/downloading-files-from-plain-batch-with-zero-dependencies

Comment: Why have you tagged this as [unix]?

Comment: unix tag removed thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample in vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,ws,fso,Srcimage,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,stRep,stFichier,oShell,oFolder,oFichier,Dimensions
Dim arrSize,intLength,intHorizontalSize,intVerticalSize,Tab
URL = "http://www.animatedimages.org/data/media/902/animated-tunisia-flag-image-0023.gif"
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\image.hta"
Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
stRep = Temp
Tab = split(url,"/")
stFichier = Tab(UBound(Tab))
Srcimage = stRep & "\" & stFichier
If Not fso.FileExists(Srcimage) Then
    Call DownloadingFile(URL,Srcimage)
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(stRep)
Set oFichier = oFolder.Items.Item(stFichier)
Dimensions = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFichier,31)
arrSize = Split(Dimensions,"x") 
'***************************************Important à savoir **********************************************
'Instead, we ended up retrieving item 31, which gave us the total dimensions of the picture,
'using an output format similar to this: ?150 x 354?
'http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/05/16/how-can-i-search-a-folder-for-all-the-image-files-that-are-not-a-specified-height-and-width.aspx
'Un grand merci à omen999 ==> 
'http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1504644/autres-langages/general-visual-basic-6-vbscript/vbscript/passage-variables-procedure/#post8163406
intLength = Len(arrSize(0))
intHorizontalSize = Right(arrSize(0),intLength -1)
intLength = Len(arrSize(1))
intVerticalSize = Left(arrSize(1),intLength - 1) 
'***************************************Important à savoir **********************************************
    Call LoadImage(Srcimage,intHorizontalSize,intVerticalSize,Timeout(51))
    ws.run "mshta.exe " & PathOutPutHTML
Else
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(stRep)
Set oFichier = oFolder.Items.Item(stFichier)
Dimensions = oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFichier,31)
arrSize = Split(Dimensions,"x")
intLength = Len(arrSize(0))
intHorizontalSize = Right(arrSize(0),intLength -1)
intLength = Len(arrSize(1))
intVerticalSize = Left(arrSize(1),intLength - 1) 
    Call LoadImage(Srcimage,intHorizontalSize,intVerticalSize,Timeout(51))
    ws.run "mshta.exe " & PathOutPutHTML
End If
'********************************************************************************************************
Function TimeOut(T)
    TimeOut = T * 1000
End Function    
'********************************************************************************************************
Sub LoadImage(Srcimage,intHorizontalSize,intVerticalSize,TimeOut)
    fhta.WriteLine "<html>"
    fhta.WriteLine "    <hta:application id=""oHTA"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        border=""none"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        caption=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        contextmenu=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        innerborder=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        scroll=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        showintaskbar=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "    />"
    fhta.WriteLine "<style>"
    fhta.WriteLine "{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }"
    fhta.WriteLine "body {background: url(" & DblQuote(Srcimage) & ") no-repeat center center fixed;}"
    fhta.WriteLine "</style>"
    fhta.WriteLine "    <script language=""VBScript"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "        Sub Window_OnLoad()"
    fhta.WriteLine "            width = " & intHorizontalSize
    fhta.WriteLine "            height = " & intVerticalSize
    fhta.WriteLine "            window.resizeTo width, height"
    fhta.WriteLine "            window.moveTo screen.availWidth\2 - width\2, screen.availHeight\2 - height\2"
    fhta.WriteLine "            idTimer = window.setTimeout(""vbscript:window.close"","& TimeOut &")"
    fhta.WriteLine "            window.setInterval ""setfocus()"",100"
    fhta.WriteLine "        End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "        Function setfocus"
    fhta.WriteLine "            Window.Focus()"
    fhta.WriteLine "        End Function"
    fhta.WriteLine "    </script>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<body>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<bgsound src=""http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Tunisie.mp3"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</body>"
    fhta.WriteLine "</html>"
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub DownloadingFile(URL,strHDLocation)
Dim Titre,objFSO,Ws,objXMLHTTP,PathScript,Tab,objADOStream,Command,Start,File
Dim MsgTitre,MsgAttente,StartTime,DurationTime,ProtocoleHTTP
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
ProtocoleHTTP = "http://"
If Left(URL,7) <> ProtocoleHTTP Then
URL = ProtocoleHTTP & URL
End if
Tab = split(url,"/")
File =  Tab(UBound(Tab))
File = Replace(File,"%20"," ")
File = Replace(File,"%28","(")
File = Replace(File,"%29",")")
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    strHDLocation = PathScript & "\" & File
    On Error Resume Next
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET",URL,false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
If Err.number <> 0 Then
   MsgBox err.description,16,err.description
   Exit Sub
   Else
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
         strHDLocation = Temp & "\" & File
         Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
         objADOStream.Open
         objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
         objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
         objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
         objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation,2 '2=adSaveCreateOverWrite
         objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End If
End if
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

And may be another samples here : [VBS/Batch Check if Download Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734096/vbs-batch-check-if-download-complete/25735194#25735194)

Answer (score 0):

Batch cannot natively download files.

To download files from the command line, you must use third party tools like cURL or wget.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell will pretty easily do this; however - even though a version is included in Windows 7 - you'll probably want to download the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Within Windows 7 or Windows 8 (and related server versions) you can map a drive to a WebDAV folder and use COPY, XCOPY or ROBOCOPY to your heart's content.  You can map the drive using command-line NET USE if you prefer.

For example, NET USE S: https:\live.sysinternals.com (or use PUSHD), and follow up with you copy commands.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Vbscript that use **PowerShell** to download and execute the file.
So in this example we download an mp3 file and we play it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyCmd,Ws,Ret
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
MyCmd = "cmd /c Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile  -WindowStyle Hidden (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3','%TEMP%\Matrix.mp3'); Start-Process %TEMP%\Matrix.mp3;"
Ret = Ws.run(MyCmd,0,True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Linux:

```
wget http://somedomain.com/somefile.xxx
```

If you are using windows, download a exe named `wget.exe`([here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)) and you will be able to use the above code.