# Classic ASP: How to save content of a page?

Tags: asp-classic

I need to create a script that generates some URL's from a specific website and copy of its content to somewhere like as txt to parse some data from it afterward. I am able to generate URL's but I have no idea how to get the pages content to a text file.

I am using classic asp and I will be appreciated if you could give me an example on how to do it.

The page I need to copy contains only plain text, which is safe to keep in a text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download Files from URL using Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496675/download-files-from-url-using-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the Fil System Object, here's a thorough example from 4Guys:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210506122630/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/040699-1.shtml

One thing to note that I've seen people run into problems with, and that's permissions. In the url tutorial above, they mention saving to your c: root for a file location:

```
set myFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", true)
```

Unless you set up special permissions in the root of your C:\ drive, which I'd strongly recommend NOT doing as it's a hge potential security risk, it will not work. I would recommend creating a folder off of the root of your web site, as permissions will probably already be in place (this is obviously reliant on what your requirements are as I'm just guessing).

Comment: thank you for the reply i also need to get content of the URL for it then i can use fso to save the file.